# Input a single time instead of asking multiple time

Tags: python, arrays, input

I am stuck with this code where it asks the user to input integers (9x9) and then the program would get coordinates according to the user's input (2-d list). The code works but I am just stuck with the input process.

Instead of asking single-time input, it asks "Enter an array" 9 times e.g. I want the output to look like this:

```
Enter an array:
359716482
867345912
413928675
398574126
546281739
172639548
984163257
621857394
735492861
```

But the code I have gives me this:

```
Enter an array:
359716482
Enter an array:
867345912
Enter an array:
413928675
Enter an array:
398574126
Enter an array:
546281739
Enter an array:
172639548
Enter an array:
984163257
Enter an array:
621857394
Enter an array:
735492861
```

```
# Goal1: user to input integer values and query a 2-dimensional array of size 9x9.
# Goal2: program should then ask the user for a pair of coordinates, (x, y), separated by a space and return the value at the position specified by the given coordinates

def gridformation(grid):                      # Creating grid using lists by asking for user input 9 times (9x9)
  for i in range(9):
    array = input("Enter an array: \n")
    grid.append(array)
  return grid

def coordinates(NumGrid):                     # Function to obtain coordinates
  coordinate = input("Enter coordinates: \n")
  split = coordinate.split(" ")               # Split coordinates by spaces

  x = int(split[0])                           # coordinate x is the first one
  y = int(split[1])                           # coordinate y is the second one

  while x != -1 or y != -1:                   # Continous while loop unless user types in -1 that stops the process
    value = NumGrid[x][y]                     # 2-d list to obtain respective number
    print("Value =", value)
    coord = input("Enter coordinates: \n")    # to keep asking for coordinate input

    splited = coord.split(" ")

    x = int(splited[0])
    y = int(splited[1])
  
  print("DONE")

def main():                                   # main function that initiates the program in order
  grid = []
  NumGrid = gridformation(grid)
  coordinates(NumGrid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: So the problem is only in the prompt?

Comment: Yes, but I saw your answer :) Thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have

```
for i in range(9):
    array = input("Enter an array: \n")
    grid.append(array)
```

Change it to:

```
print("Enter an array:")
for i in range(9):
    array = input()
    grid.append(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your data entry to match the input sequence you want.  If you want the prompt to be printed only once, then print it only once.  You put it inside the loop, which prints it every iteration.  Instead:

```
print("Enter an array, one line at a time:")
for i in range(9):
    line = input()
    grid.append(line)
return grid
```